# [Linkedin]Paging details not available for "organizationalEntityAcls" API endpoint with projections

Tags: linkedin-api

**Regarding the Paging response:**

**1.**
**case 1**: On triggering the API endpoint "**organizationalEntityAcls** ",**without any Projections** parameter ,gives me the default paging response (i.e)

**API** :**`https://api.linkedin.com/v2/organizationalEntityAcls?q=roleAssignee&oauth2_access_token=XXX;`**

**Response:**

```
{"elements":                          [{"role":"ADMINISTRATOR","roleAssignee":"urn:li:person:xxxxx","state":"APPROVED","organizationalTarget":"urn:li:organization:yyyyy"}],
**"paging":{"count":10,"start":0,"links":[]}}
```

**

**case2 :** On triggering the same API endpoint **with projections**,is not providing the paging response (i.e)

**API:**
**`https://api.linkedin.com/v2/organizationalEntityAcls?q=roleAssignee&role=ADMINISTRATOR&projection=(elements*(*,roleAssignee~(localizedFirstName, localizedLastName), organizationalTarget~(localizedName)))&oauth2_access_token=xxxx;`**

**Response:**

```
{"elements":[{
0:  
organizationalTarget~   
localizedName:"xyz",
role         :"ADMINISTRATOR",
roleAssignee :"urn:li:person:xxxxxx"
state        :"APPROVED"

roleAssignee~   
localizedLastName       "xyz"
localizedFirstName      "aaaa"
organizationalTarget    "urn:li:organizationBrand:ddddd"
}]}
```

//**End of response**

But retrieves no **PAGING RESPONSE**.

Also tried to get the paging response for the same **case2** by giving paging fields **start and count** which also yields no paging response.

Thus,need to know how to obtain the paging response with projections parameter present in API .

**2.**
Paging response **is not** confined to the limit mentioned by Start and Count field in the API call.Instead retrieves back all the results.

(i.e)**API:****`https://api.linkedin.com/v2/organizationalEntityAcls?q=roleAssignee&**start=10&count=10**&oauth2_access_token= XXX;`**

**Response:**

```
{"elements":
**0**[{"role":"ADMINISTRATOR","roleAssignee":"urn:li:person:XXX","state":"APPROVED","organizationalTarget":"urn:li:organization:YYY"},
**1**{"role":"ADMINISTRATOR","roleAssignee":"urn:li:person:XXX","state":"APPROVED","organizationalTarget":"urn:li:organization:AAA"},
**2**{"role":"ADMINISTRATOR","roleAssignee":"urn:li:person:XXX","state":"APPROVED","organizationalTarget":"urn:li:organization:ZZZZ"},
**3**{"role":"ADMINISTRATOR","roleAssignee":"urn:li:person:XXX","state":"APPROVED","organizationalTarget":"urn:li:organization:TTTT"}],
....
....
....
**20**{"role":"ADMINISTRATOR","roleAssignee":"urn:li:person:XXX","state":"APPROVED","organizationalTarget":"urn:li:organization:zzzTT"}]
...
...
..
**30**{"role":"ADMINISTRATOR","roleAssignee":"urn:li:person:XXX","state":"APPROVED","organizationalTarget":"urn:li:organization:zzzTT"}]

"paging":{"**count":10,"start":10**,"links":[]}}}
```

**//end of response**

Instead of giving result from 10 to 20 ,it retreives all results from 0 to 30.Thus need to know why the response is not limited as mentioned.

Kindly,need clarification for these queries,Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve paging by putting **paging** before elements

**Before** 
https://api.linkedin.com/v2/organizationalEntityAcls?q=roleAssignee&role=ADMINISTRATOR&projection=(elements*(*,roleAssignee~(localizedFirstName, localizedLastName), organizationalTarget~(localizedName)))&oauth2_access_token=xxxx;

**After** 
https://api.linkedin.com/v2/organizationalEntityAcls?q=roleAssignee&role=ADMINISTRATOR&projection=(**paging**, elements*(*,roleAssignee~(localizedFirstName, localizedLastName), organizationalTarget~(localizedName)))&oauth2_access_token=xxxx;